# Rails ActiveRecord associations with bulk image uploads

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, amazon-s3, carrierwave

I have a model `Item` that has an attribute `:code`.
Items are added to the database via CSV file uploads in rails. Each `:item` should have a product image associated with it.

The research I've done so far seems to suggest that bulk image uploads (think 500-1000 images) are best handled outside of rails.

My question is this: if I upload bulk images to S3, is there any way to associate images to their respective `:item`? For simplicity, let's assume that we can easily infer `:code` from each images filename.

The end goal is to display an items image with something like:

```
<%= image_tag("#{@item.image}") %>
```

Let me know if I can clarify, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You gave a little to few information (e.g. what gem do you use to store the images) for an optimal answer. So here is the answer for the given question: Add the following method into your `Item` model:

```
def image
  "example_image_#{self.code}.jpg"
end
```

Please be aware that `image_tag()` will always result into an asset pipeline path. Please see http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html#method-i-image_tag

Comment: Okay I need to clarify. I use carrierwave/fog/S3 for uploading and storage of individual files. However I was under the impression that using rails for bulk uploads was not advisable. Are you saying that I can't use `image_tag` in this instance?

Comment: You should use carrierwave methods when you use carrierwave. Uploading is not a problem. Bulk uploads neither. By bypassing these mechanisms you start an open heart surgery.

Comment: Okay, yeah it seemed like a lot of unnecessary work to get associations built in without carrierwave so glad to hear that bulk uploads aren't a big deal. Thanks.